# Finding part of a filename in Python using walk function

Tags: python-2.7, os.walk

I have a folder that has 5 sub folders for 5 different years (1956, 1976, 1987, 2001, 2005). Is there a way to search for part of a filename from each of the 5 subfolders using the walk function, i.e. Irrigated_Parcels.txt instead of Irrigated_Parcels_1956.txt? I started with the script below.

```
import os

def find(name, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(root, name)

find('*.txt', '/path/to/dir')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'glob'

The following will return a list of paths to all files matching '*.txt' in each of the subfolders

```
import glob
glob.glob('/path/to/dir/*/*.txt')
```

Also regarding the 'find' script you have started in your question: Note that a function can only return once, so the script will always only return the first path that matches.

EDIT: For the exact solution to the problem posed

```
glob.glob('/path/to/dir/*/Irrigated_Parcels.txt')
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I'm looking for something that not only returns a file that has .txt in its name but also looks for the heading 'Irrigated_Parcels' within the file names. Some of the files will have additional descriptions besides 'Irrigated_Parcels' such as 'Irrigated_Parcels_Points' which I don't want returned in the result